# MongoDB: Saving collections in a loop, inside callbacks?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collections User, Author, I'm finding active users and create new author profile for each. In the loop, after created Author profile, I want to update User collection. I created Author profile successfuly, but it doesn't work when saving User. Can you help me?

```
const activeUsers = await User.find({ status: 'active', connect_to: null }).lean()
activeUsers.forEach(user => {
    // create author profile
    const createAuthor = new Author({
        status: 1,
        name: user.name,
        from_user: user._id
    })

    createAuthor.save((err) => {
        if (err) return res.status(400).send('There is an issue with your request')

        // after create author, update user
        user.connect_to = createAuthor._id // I want to add 'connect_to' field for active users

        user.save((err) => { // it doesn't work here, err: TypeError: user.save is not a function
            if (err) return res.status(400).send('There is an issue with your request')
            return res.status(200).send('Accounts have been updated')
        })
    })
})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use this :
you shoud update users not save

```
const activeUsers = await User.find({ status: 'active', connect_to: null }).lean()
activeUsers.forEach(user => {
    // create author profile
    const createAuthor = new Author({
        status: 1,
        name: user.name,
        from_user: user._id
    })

    createAuthor.save((err) => {
        if (err) return res.status(400).send('There is an issue with your request')

        // after create author, update user
   

        User.update(user,{connect_to:createAuthor._id},(err) => { // it doesn't work here, err: TypeError: user.save is not a function
            if (err) return res.status(400).send('There is an issue with your request')
            return res.status(200).send('Accounts have been updated')
        })
    })
})
```